# downloading Google Maps at street level

Tags: google-maps

I want to download ALL of google maps(not satellite images just the map) at street level as lets say JPG images labelled as maybe the starting co-ords. need ideas for how to do this? what would be the best language/platform to implement this in? approximately how much space will I need to store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wouldlike to do this more easily and legally - take a look at openstreetmap.org

Answer (score 1):

Unless Google provides an API to do this, you are on your own to scrape the page somehow and acquire the image. And i don't think its possible to store all the images unless you have a few tera bytes to spare.